# How to save a dump, including local variables, after an unhandled exception occurs in TPL?

Tags: exception, task-parallel-library, task, dump, unhandled-exception

My idea of handling exceptions is as follows.

When an unhandled exception occurs, I want to save a dump with full memory, including local variables available at the line where the exception happened. Then I can analyze that dump and either prevent the exception from happening again or handle it with `try`...`catch`.

I almost achieved my goal by simply handling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. It fires every time an unhandled exception occurs and its call stack includes the line of the exception, so after saving a dump I have all the data I need including local variables.

However, that solution doesn't work with TPL. After encountering an unhandled exception a task terminates and only then allows me to access the exception through various means (checking `Task.Exception`, handling `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event, using continuation with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`, using `Task.Wait()` or `await`...). Those methods obviously do not allow me to include local variables from within a task, since the task itself already terminated.

Is there something I can do to catch unhandled exceptions occuring within tasks before those tasks are terminated? And if so, can I then save a dump including local variables from within those tasks?

Here are some ideas for a solution I came up with:

1. I can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`, but from within that event I can't check whether an exception will be handled in a `catch` block or not. And obviously I don't want to save a dump for some exception that will be later handled in a `catch` block. But, since it looks like the event handles only one `AppDomain`, I could theoretically run all the code placed within `try`...`catch` blocks from some other `AppDomain`. But I have no idea how to achieve that nor whether it would actually work, not to mention possible drawbacks.
2. Is it possible to write an alternative to `try`...`catch` in IL, which won't leave the `try` block after encountering an exception, thus allowing access to local variables?
3. I can simply use `try`...`catch` and declare my local variables before the `try` block, but I treat that solution as the last resort, since it's ugly.

Comment: Couldn't you enclose all your `Task`s in a exception handling code? Something like `Task.Factory.StartNew(HandleExceptions(() => /* your code */))`.

Comment: Have you tried IntelliTrace?

Comment: @svick, how would that help me access the variables within the code in case of an exception?

Comment: @StephenCleary, I've just tested IntelliTrace and although it does allow me to go back to the line within the task where the exception was thrown, it doesn't show me any local variables in the 'Locals' window, only the exception itself. But I think I can somehow force it to show the variables, I will look into it. From what I've read so far, IntelliTrace doesn't compare to normal debugging experience, but if there are no better solutions, it will have to do.

Comment: @humanista If you can access the variables from `UnhandledException`, then I think you should be able to do the same in a `catch` block inside `HandleExceptions`.

Comment: @svick, no, it doesn't work like that. `UnhandledException` event has the line of the exception in its call stack, `catch` block hasn't.